# How to share string or file between a application as sender and receiver in react native using wifi or hotspot?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to find a way to share a string or a file from a react native application using wifi/hotspot.

I have tried with npm react native p2p wifi. Which doesn't work with lot of devices.

Can someone help with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try some other libraries as well like below .

```
react-native-wifi-hotspot
```

check [this](https://github.com/assemmohamedali/react-native-wifi-hotspot) 


Hope it works .!